# Setting variable for use later in a case construct

Tags: linux, bash, shell, conditional-statements

I have this practice problem that is asking me to take my existing code and insert variables for letter grades into the existing 'IF' statements for use in a case construct that reads off a sentence based on the letter grade assigned. The problem I'm having is how to set the variable in the first place, ie. do I need to do a whole new IF/ECHO line for the variable? How do I even word it in the first place?

Would it be something like grade=A?

Here's what I have so far: (EDITED TO INCLUDE SUGGESTIONS)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash shell script to calculate student average
# Usage: ./grade1.sh

# Declare some integer type variables
declare -i test1
declare -i test2
declare -i test3
declare -i test4
declare -i lab
declare -i sum

echo
echo "=================="
echo "Grade Calculator  "
echo "=================="
echo
read -p "Enter first name: " firstname
read -p "Enter last name: " lastname
echo
read -p "Enter test score 1: " test1
read -p "Enter test score 2: " test2
read -p "Enter test score 3: " test3
read -p "Enter test score 4: " test4
read -p "Enter lab score: " lab

sum=$test1+$test2+$test3+$test4+$lab
average=$((sum/5))

VAR1=A
VAR2=B
VAR3=C
VAR4=D
VAR5=F

if [ $average -ge 90 ]; then
   echo "Course grade: $VAR1"    
elif [ $average -ge 80 ]; then
   echo "Course grade: $VAR2"
elif [ $average -ge 70 ]; then
   echo "Course grade: $VAR3"
elif [ $average -ge 60 ]; then
   echo "Course grade: $VAR4"
elif [ $average -le 60 ]; then
   echo "Course grade: $VAR5"
fi

echo
echo "Grade results . . ."
echo "Student name: $firstname $lastname"
echo "Total points: $sum"
echo "Course average: $average"
echo

case $grade in

A) echo "An 'A' represents superior course work."
    ;;
B) echo "A 'B' represents above average course work."
    ;;
C) echo "A 'C' represents average course work."
    ;;
D) echo "A 'D' represents below average course work."
    ;;
F) echo "An 'F' represents failing course work."
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `sum=$test1+$test2+$test3+$test4+$lab` does not perform arithmetic.  Instead, sum is going to be a string like `85+4+76+57+84`

Comment: I am concerned more with the mechanics of getting the letter grade to be able to be called into a case logic statement stating "An F is god awful...", etc.

Comment: I really don't see why you need 70 lines to illustrate your question here. Note the guidance in the Help Center on building a [mcve] -- and note that word **minimal**; a code sample should be the *shortest possible thing* that lets someone else reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sorry! I am just trying to figure stuff out. I will shorten my posts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The task, as you stated it, doesn't make very much sense .... it would make sense if we have the number of grades and the shresholds completely variable. But, well, it's a practice problem, so they might require you doing some nonsense, just for the exercise.

As it is an exercise, I'll give you some pointers, but don't write down the whole solution.

Assuming that you are really supposed to do what you are asking here (and did not misunderstood the task), you are supposed to replace the literal grades (A, B, C, D, F) by variables. Since you have 5 grades, you need either 5 variables or an array of 5 elements. You asked for variables, so for this exercise, this is the way to go.

Since you have 5 variables, you need to invent 5 different names, for example

```
this=A
is=B
a=C
silly=D
exercise=F # Note: grade E does not exist
```

You can write these definition somewhere before they are first used, and feel free to use variable names which suit you better. Now bash knows about these variables, you can use them, for instance:

```
elif [ $average -ge 60 ]; then
  echo "Course grade: $silly"
```

Now to two things you didn't ask for, but might be interested to know:

First, the calculation of `average` in your code is incorrect. If you set all tests and the lab to 1, you will get an average of 5 (try it out).

Second, in your `case` statement, you are using a variable `grade`, which you don't set anywhere. For example, at the place that you found out that the grade is D (and you did find this out, because you do an `echo` of this fact), you should set the variable

```
 grade=$silly
```

Comment: Maybe also point out that `sum=$test1+$test2+$test3+$test4+$lab` assigns a string variable which contains (at least) four plusses, not the result of the arithmetic evaluation. You'd need to use this in arithmetic context to get that. `sum=$((test1+test2+test3+test4+lab))` where the dollar signs are not necessary inside the double parentheses.

Comment: Equivalently, but quirkily, you could do `echo "Total points: $((sum))"` to have the arithmetic be evaluated when you print the total points.  But that's just weird; I'm pretty sure the OP wanted and expected the shell to evaluate the arithmetic at assignment time.

Comment: @tripleee : Since this is an exercise, I wanted the OP to figure this out by himself. If we tell him the complete solution, he doesn't learn much.

Comment: Oh, completely agree; but the absence of arithmetic evaluation is a huge surprise to many people so I thought it'd be worth pointing out.

Comment: It is vague and I apologize. I'm still figuring out the lingo here.

Basically, I need to be able to assign each letter grade as a variable so that after the script runs, it also displays a message based on what letter grade the student received. So if they got an A, the case logic part of the script would print a message saying the appropriate thing. I just don't know how to define the letter grades as variables within the existing conditional statement so that they can be used in the case logic part.

Comment: @tripleee : Funnily, by virtue of the way `average` is calculated, there is indeed arithmetic evaluation going on - try `x=4+5; echo $((x))`. While storing a string in `sum` instead of a number, is a bit unconventional, but not by itself an error. The error comes because the OP was not mathematically careful in how he then used this string in the arithmetic expression. Hint: Division binds higher than addition.

Comment: @Hebruiser : Well, in this case, my answer indeed should answer your question....

Comment: Yeah, the error would only be visible where they did `echo "$sum"`. But it's basically also why the average was wrong; if the terms had already been summed, there would be no precedence problem.

Comment: I edited the OP to show my latest scramble. I still am not seeing anything from the case statements. Am I making this more difficult than it needs to be?

Answer (score 1):

This is a circumstance where you can let the shell (bash specifically) help you with your problem by utilizing *arrays* to help you build your text output and let *character classes* help with matches in your `case` statement.

For example, since you know you are grading on the traditional `A-F` `90-50` breakpoints, you can create several arrays to allow you index all associated information, e.g.

```
ltrgrades=(  A  B  C  D  F )
numgrades=( 90 80 70 60 50 )
prefixes=(  An  A  A  A An )
comments=(  "superior"
            "above average"
            "average"
            "below average"
            "failing" )
```

A function can handle all your output needs per-student by passing the associated index as its first argument:

```
results() {
    echo
    echo "Grade results . . ."
    echo "Student name  : $firstname $lastname"
    echo "Total points  : $sum"
    echo "Course average: $average"
    echo
    echo "Course grade  : ${ltrgrades[$1]}"
    echo
    echo "${prefixes[$1]} '${ltrgrades[$1]}' represents ${comments[$1]} course work."
}
```

Utilizing a `heredoc` simplifies providing multi-line output:

```
## use a heredoc for multi-line text
cat << EOF
"=================="
"Grade Calculator  "
"=================="
EOF
```

(**note:** you could utilize a heredoc within the `results` function)

Finally, you can use *character classes* as your `case` matches and `'*'` to mark the default case, e.g.

```
case "${average%.*}" in
    1??     )   results 0;;
    9[0-9]  )   results 0;;
    8[0-9]  )   results 1;;
    7[0-9]  )   results 2;;
    6[0-9]  )   results 3;;
    *       )   results 4;;
esac
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash shell script to calculate student average
# Usage: ./grade1.sh

ltrgrades=(  A  B  C  D  F )
numgrades=( 90 80 70 60 50 )
prefixes=(  An  A  A  A An )
comments=(  "superior"
            "above average"
            "average"
            "below average"
            "failing" )

results() {
    echo
    echo "Grade results . . ."
    echo "Student name  : $firstname $lastname"
    echo "Total points  : $sum"
    echo "Course average: $average"
    echo
    echo "Course grade  : ${ltrgrades[$1]}"
    echo
    echo "${prefixes[$1]} '${ltrgrades[$1]}' represents ${comments[$1]} course work."
}

## use a heredoc for multi-line text
cat << EOF
"=================="
"Grade Calculator  "
"=================="
EOF

read -p "Enter first name  : " firstname
read -p "Enter last name   : " lastname
echo
read -p "Enter test score 1: " test1
read -p "Enter test score 2: " test2
read -p "Enter test score 3: " test3
read -p "Enter test score 4: " test4
read -p "Enter lab score   : " lab

sum=$((test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + lab))
average=$(echo "scale=2; $sum / 5" | bc)

case "${average%.*}" in
    1??     )   results 0;;
    9[0-9]  )   results 0;;
    8[0-9]  )   results 1;;
    7[0-9]  )   results 2;;
    6[0-9]  )   results 3;;
    *       )   results 4;;
esac
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash grades.sh
"=================="
"Grade Calculator  "
"=================="
Enter first name  : John
Enter last name   : Doe

Enter test score 1: 85
Enter test score 2: 93
Enter test score 3: 94
Enter test score 4: 91
Enter lab score   : 92

Grade results . . .
Student name  : John Doe
Total points  : 455
Course average: 91.00

Course grade  : A

An 'A' represents superior course work.


$ bash grades.sh
"=================="
"Grade Calculator  "
"=================="
Enter first name  : Mary
Enter last name   : Jane

Enter test score 1: 86
Enter test score 2: 93
Enter test score 3: 72
Enter test score 4: 71
Enter lab score   : 77

Grade results . . .
Student name  : Mary Jane
Total points  : 399
Course average: 79.80

Course grade  : C

A 'C' represents average course work.


$ bash grades.sh
"=================="
"Grade Calculator  "
"=================="
Enter first name  : Sally
Enter last name   : Smith

Enter test score 1: 55
Enter test score 2: 61
Enter test score 3: 42
Enter test score 4: 58
Enter lab score   : 59

Grade results . . .
Student name  : Sally Smith
Total points  : 275
Course average: 55.00

Course grade  : F

An 'F' represents failing course work.
```

Since the grades are computed as a floating-point value using `bc`, you can, and probably should, handle rounding (e.g a `79.5` rounds to `80` while a `79.4` remains `79`. You can handle that with another variable `score` with something similar to:

```
sum=$((test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + lab))
average=$(echo "scale=2; $sum / 5" | bc)
fract=${average#*.}
score=${average%.*}
(( ${fract:0:1} >= '5')) && ((score++))

case $score in
    1??     )   results 0;;
    9[0-9]  )   results 0;;
    8[0-9]  )   results 1;;
    7[0-9]  )   results 2;;
    6[0-9]  )   results 3;;
    *       )   results 4;;
esac
```

Now `Mary Jane's` grade with an average of `79.80` is rounded to `80` a `B` instead of a `C`. It's up to you to determine how rounding is handled, this is just one way to approach it. You could re-write `results` to show both the computed `average` and rounded `score`, e.g.

```
results() {
cat << EOF

Grade results . . .
Student name  : $firstname $lastname
Total points  : $sum
Course average: $average  ($score)

Course grade  : ${ltrgrades[$1]}

${prefixes[$1]} '${ltrgrades[$1]}' represents ${comments[$1]} course work.
EOF
}
```